# VBA Append Character to Beginning of Filename in Directory

Tags: vba

I am wondering if anyone can help me edit this VBA script so that it not only moves the files (this part is complete by the way), but it also appends a 0 to the front of the filename (this part has not been started.

So, if the original filename is 123456789.tif, then the resultant will be 0123456789.tif.

Thank you!

```
Sub MoveIfFilelength()
'This script moves files from a source directory to a final directory based on the number of characters in the filename (e.g., 14, as below)

Dim srcDir As String
Dim dstDir As String
Dim f As String

srcDir = "S:\\" 'Input source directory
dstDir = "S:\\" 'Input destination directory

f = Dir(srcDir)
Do While f <> ""
  If Len(f) = 13 Then Name srcDir & "\" & f As dstDir & "\" & f 'Input filename length
  f = Dir()
  Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Name .. As` is the move operation which is semantically a rename already, so specify the new name as `"\0" & f`:

```
If Len(f) = 13 Then Name srcDir & "\" & f As dstDir & "\0" & f
```

Comment: You got it...thank you much. Thanks for the answer AND explanation as well.